# Feature Request: Salary calculator for a broader field

Tags: feature-request

When I got the mail that the Salary Calculator got updated, I was exited, especially since I am going to graduate from university soon.

But when I tried to calculate a prospective salary I noticed that it is very much narrowed down to software engineering/programming roles, while I want to do hardware development (ASIC/FPGA)*.
So my request would be if the calculator could allow a broader range of jobs.

Best regards,
mox

*verilog/systemverilog or vhdl are no supported languages

Comment: Since the data they use is data from the survey, more people who participate in hardware development need to take the survey for more realistic data points.